# How do I capture select menu with formsubmit

Tags: html, css, github, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am creating a website using Bootstrap 5 and I am hosting the website using GitHub pages. I also used Bootstrap 5 to create a form on the website. I am using [Formsubmit](https://formsubmit.co) to send the info submitted to the form to my email. When I submit the form I get an email that gives me the info from every field except the select menu. It only gives me the value of the selection instead of the name. This is what the email I get looks like [image]

### Test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Submit Ticket | </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contact.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ticket-form.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM START -->
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5" id="container-background">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Submit A Ticket</h1>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/email@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Number" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="etel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="tel" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Type of Work</label>
            <select class="form-select select-control" data-width="auto" aria-placeholder="" name="type of work" required>
                <option selected>Select A Category</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="1" name="type of work">CCTV / Alarm Systems</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="2">Desktop/Laptop</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="3">Fiber Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="4">General Tasks</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="5">Kiosk</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="6">Low Voltage Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="7">Networking</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="8">Point of Sale (POS)</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="9">Printer</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="10">Pro A/V, Digital Signage</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="11">Project management</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="12">Server Hardware/Software</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="13">Software Development</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="14">Structured Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="15">Telecom / VOIP</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="16">Other</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Description of the Problem</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the problem clearly. (What is the problem, when the problem started, where did the problem begin, etc. )" name="problem description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Required Materials/Equipment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What equipment or materials are required to resolve the issue?" name="needed materials/equipment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Ticket Request Submission!">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </form>
  </div>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM CLOSE -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
.form-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

.select-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

#submit-button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#submit-button:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}
```

```css
.form-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

.select-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

#submit-button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#submit-button:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Submit Ticket | </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contact.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ticket-form.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM START -->
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5" id="container-background">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Submit A Ticket</h1>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/email@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Number" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="etel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="tel" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Type of Work</label>
            <select class="form-select select-control" data-width="auto" aria-placeholder="" name="type of work" required>
                <option selected>Select A Category</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="1" name="type of work">CCTV / Alarm Systems</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="2">Desktop/Laptop</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="3">Fiber Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="4">General Tasks</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="5">Kiosk</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="6">Low Voltage Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="7">Networking</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="8">Point of Sale (POS)</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="9">Printer</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="10">Pro A/V, Digital Signage</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="11">Project management</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="12">Server Hardware/Software</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="13">Software Development</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="14">Structured Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="15">Telecom / VOIP</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="16">Other</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Description of the Problem</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the problem clearly. (What is the problem, when the problem started, where did the problem begin, etc. )" name="problem description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Required Materials/Equipment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What equipment or materials are required to resolve the issue?" name="needed materials/equipment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Ticket Request Submission!">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </form>
  </div>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM CLOSE -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how usually select input implemented, they send the selected item
id as value and that value is linked to an item on the database, that's why usually you wouldn't need the name.

if you don't have a reference in the database for those value and you just want the name, you could just set the select value items to the names

**Like this:**

```css
.form-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

.select-control {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}

#submit-button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    width: 180px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#submit-button:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Submit Ticket | </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/contact.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ticket-form.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM START -->
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5" id="container-background">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Submit A Ticket</h1>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/email@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Number" class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="etel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="tel" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Type of Work</label>
            <select class="form-select select-control" data-width="auto" aria-placeholder="" name="type of work" required>
                <option selected>Select A Category</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="CCTV / Alarm Systems" name="type of work">CCTV / Alarm Systems</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Desktop/Laptop">Desktop/Laptop</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Fiber Cabling">Fiber Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="General Tasks">General Tasks</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Kiosk">Kiosk</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Low Voltage Cabling">Low Voltage Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Networking">Networking</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Point of Sale (POS)">Point of Sale (POS)</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Printer">Printer</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Pro A/V, Digital Signage">Pro A/V, Digital Signage</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Project management">Project management</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Server Hardware/Software">Server Hardware/Software</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Software Development">Software Development</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Structured Cabling">Structured Cabling</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Telecom / VOIP">Telecom / VOIP</option>
                <option class="select-control" value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Description of the Problem</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the problem clearly. (What is the problem, when the problem started, where did the problem begin, etc. )" name="problem description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Message" class="form-label">Required Materials/Equipment</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What equipment or materials are required to resolve the issue?" name="needed materials/equipment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Ticket Request Submission!">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </form>
  </div>
  <!-- TICKET RQUEST FORM CLOSE -->
    
</body>
</html>
```